# Display modal on img hover in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might be confusing but I'm essentially trying to open a modal with an image when someone hovers over that specific image in say a table or something.  I have it where if you hover over that image it makes it larger, but I want it to open within a modal.

Here is a snippet of my code

```js
RenderItems(){
var items = this.state.ItemList;
var allItems = this.state.AllItems;
var rows = [];

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if(this.state.ItemSelected == "All Items"){
                rows.push(
                    <tr style={{backgroundColor: '#B7BCDF'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)} key={i}>
                        <td  className="PartImage" style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            <img src={PartImage} alt="" width="50%"></img>
                        </td>

                        <td style={{width: '111px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].PartName}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '94px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].Vendor}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].PartNumber}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            ${items[i].Price.toFixed(2)}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].QuantityOnHand}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }

return (

            <div className="TableScroll">
                <table className="TableRows">
                    <tbody>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        );


}

  render(){
   return(
    <div className="container">
      <div className="PartImageModal">
         <div className="ImageModalContent">
             <img src="">I'm an Image in a modal</img>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   );

  }
```

And here is my css for this portion

```js
.PartImage img:hover{

}

.PartImageModal{
    position: relative;
    width: 35%;
    height: 45%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
}

.ImageModalContent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

My first thought was that I could change my class PartImage img:hover to:

```js
.PartImage img:hover{
 .PartImageModal{
   display: block;
 }
}
```

but this is not allowed in CSS.

If anyone has any ideas on how I could accomplish this, I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement a gallery-style display with a `click` event opening a modal.

Hopefully this gives you somewhere to start!

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
      modal.classList.remove('hidden');
      modal.classList.add('show');
      modal.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = this.src;     
  });
});

 document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener("click", function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
      modal.classList.add('hidden');
      modal.classList.remove('show');
 });
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 30%;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#modal img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.modal-state.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal-state.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/restaurant-view.jpg"/></td>
         <td><img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/plane.jpg"/></td>
         <td><img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/anchors.jpg"/></td>
         <td><img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/hand-water.jpg"/></td>
         <td><img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/graf.jpg"/></td>
         <td><img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/cyclists.jpg"/></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="modal" class="modal-state hidden">
  <img src="#" />
</div>
```

What I would do from here:

- Look into how you would change this from a `click` triggered event, to a `hover` / `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` / `mouseover` effect
- Style your modal appropriately
- Implement recursive HTML output if necessary for your HTML structure

If the images don't load, view this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mzt8ejd/)

Let me know if this helps you any / clarifies any questions. If not, let me know and I'll try to provide you a more specific answer!

Comment: I mean I know how to do this with an onClick() event in react, but I guess this doesn't really answer my question.  Also my images are dynamically allocated not static, so there's some differences here.  I do appreciate the answer though.